# How to add the lineCap property to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, countdown

I'm trying to change the lineCap property to "round" on the canvas of the [TimeCircles](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php) plugin.

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineWidth = 15;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

What is missing? Complete code in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYKRJZ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');` returns an array with all the `canvas` elements.

`Array` doesn't have `getContext` method. So simply select the canvas by adding `[0]` like the following.

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineWidth = 15;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

Demo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYKGXO)